# How to track how long the movie player is running in iOS

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have used MPMoviePlayerController for playing a movie file in one of my application. It is working fine. I have a requirement where I have to track "for how long the movie is being played by the user?". I am using Omniture for that. 
I am stuck at knowing the duration of playing time from start
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to record when the movie starts :

```
self.movieStartDate = [NSDate date];
```

and when the movie has finished (or gets stopped), get how long it's been since then

```
NSTimeInterval duration = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.movieStartDate];
```

`duration` will then contain the amount of time since the movie started, in seconds.

But remember that a movie can stop because the app enters the background / becomes inactive so you'll have to listen out for those notifications as well as the ones from the movie player :)